# Can we use widget="guage" in form view in odoo 10.0 and in master branch?

Tags: widget, odoo-10, formview

I want to make gauge view in form view of wizard can i use same structure as we use in kanban view? and yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like the following in Kanban view

```
<div class="o_assignation_leads_count">
     <field name="maximum_user_leads" invisible="1"/>
     <field name="leads_count" widget="gauge" options="{'max_field': 'maximum_user_leads'}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You have asked for Odoo 10

Comment: Also mention master branch(odoo 11). and i also try in odoo 10 in that its not work.